# File gets ruined after macro attempt to save it as .dif

Tags: excel, vba

I'm stuck with this procedure:

```
Today = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set DestinationWb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet").Copy Before:=DestinationWb.Sheets(1)
DestinationWb.Sheets("Foglio1").Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
DestinationWb.SaveAs Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=LCase(Environ("Path")) & "\" & Today & "_MyName.dif", FileFilter:="Formato interscambio dati (*.dif), *.dif", Title:="My Data Export")
DestinationWb.Close
```

It works and it creates a file with .dif extension but for some reasons the destination file content gets encripted and I can't read or reuse it.

Anyone has ever experienceed something similar? how to solve?

Comment: Have you tried or considered CSV?

Comment: Did you try something like `DestinationWb.SaveAs Filename:="yourpath\dif_file.dif" _
        , FileFormat:=xlDIF`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file doesn't get ruined - it's simply not stored in the *file format* you expect. You don't tell Excel to store it in a specific format (in your case likely in *Data Interchange format*). Just by giving a file extension doesn't advice the SaveAs to change the format, so Excel will store the file as regular Excel file.

You can check this by renaming your saved file to `.xlsx` and try to open it with Excel - it should work.

You will need to tell the SaveAs the format you want using the `FileFormat`-parameter. File formats and the named constants are described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat. In your case, you need probably `xlDIF`.

```
Dim fileName
fileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=LCase(Environ("Path")) & "\" & Today & "_MyName.dif", FileFilter:="Formato interscambio dati (*.dif), *.dif", Title:="My Data Export")
DestinationWb.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=xlDIF
```